# How to create a read-only snapshot in LVM, and then rollback to it after some work?

Tags: lvm, restore, backup, sandbox

What are the commands to use in LVM in case I want to:

1. create a read-only snapshot of a volume;
2. (do some experiments in the volume);
3. and then rollback the volume to the snapshot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for `lvconvert --merge`. From the man page:

> --merge
>
> > Merges  a  snapshot into its origin volume.  To check if your kernel
> >     supports this feature, look for `snapshot-merge` in the output of
> >     `dmsetup targets`. If both the origin and snapshot volume are not open
> >     the merge will start immediately.  Otherwise, the merge will start the
> >     first time either the origin  or snapshot are activated and both are
> >     closed.  Merging a snapshot into an origin that cannot be closed, for
> >     example a root filesystem, is deferred until the next time the origin
> >     volume is activated.  When merging starts, the resulting logical
> >     volume  will  have  the  origin's  name, minor number  and  UUID.
> >     While the merge is in progress, reads or writes to the origin appear
> >     as they were directed to the snapshot being merged. **When the merge
> >     finishes, the merged snapshot is removed.**  Multiple snapshots may be
> >     specified on the commandline or a @tag may be  used  to  specify
> >     multiple snapshots be merged to their respective origin.

Assume you have a logical volume vg0/system which contains your / filesystem.

```
# create a read-only snapshot
lvcreate -pr --snapshot --name system_snapshot vg0/system
# upgrade or something
# if it fails, reboot and do this from a livecd
lvconvert --merge vg0/system_snapshot
# reboot again and you have your old system back
```

The reboots are only needed because in this scenario you can't unmount the filesystem. If it's not the / fs, unmount is enough.

Keep in mind that the snapshot will deleted after the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And if one doesn't give the `-pr` (`--permission r`) option to `lvcreate`, will the snapshot be read-only by default? ([Does LVM allow writable snapshots](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19210/4319) at all? If yes, an alternative scenario could be possible, where the temporary experiments wouldn't be visible in the main volume, but would be performed in the temporary writable snapshot.)

Comment: The default is RW.

Comment: You shouldn't do the merge from a live CD , you can issue the command and after reboot it would merge automatically.