# Non-persistent differencing file

Tags: filesystems, rsync, virtualization

I have a large file (5-10 GB) and want to access this file in a special file system with the following conditions/features:

1. There is a single process that reads and write on the file.
2. When the process writes to some position of the file and reads the same position afterwards, the new values are returned (the file seems changed).
3. When the file system receives a rollback signal, the file will restore to the original state.

Theoretically I can imagine of a mechanism where the changes are saved on an auxiliary file, and there is a virtual file system which manages all this, giving a visualization of a non-persistent file to the end-used. Does anyone know of an implementation of this?

Comment: After some research, it seems a copy-on-write mechanism will help much here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a storage mechanism with a snapshot feature. Under Linux, the [Btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) filesystem supports snapshot. You can make them with the [`btrfs`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs(command) command.

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot myvolume mysnapshot
… work on mysnapshot, not on the original file …
btrfs subvolume delete mysnapshot
```

Another filesystem that supports snapshots is [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), which is native to Solaris and also available on Linux and *BSD. You can make them with the [`zfs`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcya/index.html) command.

```
zfs snapshot myvolume@mysnapshot
…
zfs rollback mysnapshot
```

Under Linux, you can also do the snapshotting at the [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) level. See [How to create a read-only snapshot in LVM, and then rollback to it after some work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/how-to-create-a-read-only-snapshot-in-lvm-and-then-rollback-to-it-after-some-wo/18914#18914)